# Javascript autosubmit form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form that I need to submit automatically... (the fields are already filled and its complicated to explain why but it IS necessary to do it this way)..
I know how to autosubmit the form using Javascript but the only problem I have is that there is more than 1 submit button.. and I need 1 in particular to be submitted...
thanks in advance

EDIT2(source):

```
<I put the javascript in the head... />
<FORM ACTION="PDF.php" name="form" METHOD="post">
<A whole bunch of inputs />
<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="form-save" VALUE="Save Changes" >
<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="form-submit" VALUE="Submit" >
<input type="submit" name="print" id="print" value="Download PDF" />
</form>
```

Comment: You really should explain why you think you need to auto-submit a form, because usually it's a sign of using the wrong technology to solve the wrong problem. Hint: What about users without JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#yourbuttonid").click();
```

EDIT:

```
<form>
    ... 
   <input type="submit" id="myFirstsubmit" /> 
   <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" /> 
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#mysubmit").click();}); 
</script>
```

Comment: so I can just do: <input type="submit" onload="$("#mybuttonid").click();" /> or can I just do "click();"?

Comment: ...
<input type="submit" id="mysubmit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#mysubmit").click();});
</script>

Comment: Tried ALL the answers given... not working.. is there a way I can use a class instead of an ID?

Comment: of course, just add a class to your submit button and call `$('.mysubmit').click()` instead; note the `.` instead of `#`

Comment: Can you edit your question with your html source code please?

Comment: Do you reference Jquery js files in your head section?

Comment: for some reason I got something to work.. I guess I has more than 1 document ready function or something... idk.. but its working... this is my final result code....................................................................................... <?php if($_GET['print']==TRUE){
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#print").trigger("click");}); </script>'; 
 } ?>

Answer (score 4):

instead of going for a `click` event on a `submit` button, you can call `submit` of a form object from javascript.

Example :

```
<head>
<title>Auto Submit Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var form = document.getElementById("PDFGenerationForm");
        form.submit();
    };

    function OnFormSubmit() {
        alert("Submitting form.");
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="PDFGenerationForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="OnFormSubmit">
    <!--Any input tags go in here-->
</form>
```

This editor won't let me paste the whole HTML in here. So, it is in fragments.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to click a specific button, add this script to the end of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // press the button
    var myButton = document.getElementById("idOfTheButtonToClick");
    myButton.click();
</script>
```

This assumes your button has an ID.

Answer (score 0):

1) Here is a working auto-submit method: when page is loaded, the form will be immediately autosubmited (the values can be set with php variables too.)

```
<form action="page.php" name="FORM_NAME" method="post">
<input type="text" name="example1" value="YOUR_VALUE" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">document.forms["FORM_NAME"].submit();</SCRIPT>
```

or use for any form on that page:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

2) you can use button-click (called after 1 second):

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">setInterval(function () {document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();}, 1000);</SCRIPT>
```