# How to autosubmit a form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onchange

I have a form with an input text field which imports data every couple of seconds and display it in the form field , let us say :

```
<input name="code" id="code" type="text" size="64" maxlength="128" />
```

and a submit button and my form has the formname form1.
I want the submit button to be clicked as soon as the data in the form field is changed.
I did try to do the following. In the header I did add the follwoing javascript:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
function send_data()
{
document.form1.submit();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

and on the form :

```
<input name="code" id="code" type="text" size="64" maxlength="128" onchange="send_data();" />
```

but it didn`t work..

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: could you display the `<form>` tag. It needs to have the `action` attribute in order to have the `.submit()` to work.

Comment: I already have an action but not the submit() , here <form name="form1" method="post" action="form_response.php"> .. Is there any turnaround for this ?

Comment: Caveat: Avoid naming the submit button(or any other form element) name="submit" or the submit() will fail in some browsers. Call it name="btnSubmit" or something, anything but "submit".

Comment: look at - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102889/javascript-autosubmit-form/15633817#15633817

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="" id="input" />
    <button type="submit"></button:>
</form>

<script>
function send_data() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.onchange = send_data;
}
</script>
```

But I'd add a few caveats:

1. I'm assuming there is only one form on the page. You would be safer assigning and  ID to your form and using `getElementById` and referencing that instead of `document.forms[x]`
2. The change event will only happen after you lose focus on the input, which I probably what you want? Just making sure it's expected behavior
3. Without knowing why you need to do this, I'd note that it could potentially be very annoying to the user, as submission will trigger a new page load. You may be better off doing a submission via ajax so as not to disrupt the user's browsing. If you do this, I strongly recommend a JS library to handle this.

Comment: also, some coding style notes: use unobtrusive JS instead of doing it inline; use html5 style script tags (lowercase, no language attributes).

Comment: I am developing a small webapp, and to automate the process without the need for a user interaction, I need to submit this form as soon as the code changes. This is still the beginning as I need the info submitted to an xml file. I hope this clarifies what I am doing and why I need this.

Comment: I think for a UI perspective, you'll be better served by having that submit be Ajax, and then alert the user (via a modal window, perhaps) that it was successfully saved or had an error. I recommend making your life easier and using a library (jQuery, YUI, Dojo, etc), which simplifies x-browser issues, ajax handling, etc.

Comment: thank you, I will take alook at Ajax but i thought i would ask here first because in the end ajax came from javascript. thanks again

Comment: Your welcome. I imagine you'll have reason to ask more than a few question on SO as you develop this :-)

Comment: Sure :-) I have figured that the form is working when I inout any code manually and then click outside the box. However if the code is automatically changed as it is now, and I click outside the box, nothing will happen.