# 1 form - two different lists

Tags: php, forms

Ok so i have this is form

it works fine when i click submit but now I would it like do something else.

when the form is submitted i would like for the email and name fields to be added to my 
getresponse list in addition to where it is going right now.

So essentially when the form is submitted i want the user to opt-in into two different lists. I know i may have to user the get response api key to add contacts. I do not own the cgi code so i cannot do it that away. Also i am not a programmer so I am not sure what the best way to go around doing this.

So thank you guys in advance for helping me find a solution for this

```
 <form action="/cgi-bin/join.cgi" method="POST" name="info" id='info' onsubmit="return checkForm2();">
              <input type=hidden name=page value=1>
              <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="570" align="center" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="500" align="center" valign="middle">
                    <table border=1 width="80%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="bordercolor:#000000" align="center">
                      <tr bgcolor="#eaeaea">
                        <td>
                          <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align="center">
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><b>First name</b></td><td width=10>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=text name=firstname value="" size=15 maxlength=20 id='firstname'>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><b>Last name</b></td><td width=10>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=text name=lastname value="" size=25 maxlength=30 id='lastname'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><b>Email address</b></td><td width=10>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=text name=email value="" size=25 maxlength=100 id='email'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><b>Re-type Email</b></td><td width=10>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=text name=email2 value="" size=25 maxlength=100 id='email2'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><b>Select a password</b></td><td width=10>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=password name=password size=20 maxlength=20 id='password'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td><b>Re-type password</b></td><td width=10>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=password name=password2 size=20 maxlength=20 id='password2'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3 align=center>
                                <input type="submit" name="send" value="Create Account and Continue ..." onClick="leaving=false" tabindex="6" style="background-color:#26701b; color:#ffffff; font-family:Verdana,Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; border-left: 1 solid #a0a0a0; border-top: 1 solid #a0a0a0; border-right: 1 solid #000000; border-bottom: 1 solid #000000; padding: 2 2 2 2; outline: #a0a0a0 solid 2px; width:335px">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3 align=center>
                                <img src="/images/transdot.gif" height=8 width=1 alt=""><br>
                                <img src="/images/secure.gif" height=12 width=12 alt="">
                                <font class=fine><a href="/privacy_w.cgi" onClick="leaving=false">Email Security Guarantee & Privacy Policy</a></font><br><br>

                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: After the form is submitted, do what you're doing now, and then below that, create a bunch of hidden html fields to store the variables in the proper fields needed for the getresponse api, and then do an autosubmit on that page.

Comment: To expand on my above comment, you can do an autosubmit in javascript  using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7430767/1347170 except of course, all your inputs and submit button would be hidden.

Comment: I dont fully understand - like i said i am very new to coding

Comment: Okay, before I start writing code, where did you get the code that you posted above? What is that join.cgi file?

Comment: I got it from the company's website i do not own it. so i cannot make edits to it that just the cgi they provide

Comment: all i know is the join.cgi file is what allows the user to optin into  first list

Comment: can any one else help?