# How to Auto Submit Form Using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add code auto Auto Submit Form using JS once the page finish load
I need it submit the inputs values too
Submit and the captcha response works good when I click manually automatic work but didnt submit with  input "g-recaptcha-response" value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo $captcha_site_key ?>"></script>
</head>
    <form action="check.php" id="myform" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response">
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo $captcha_site_key ?>', {action:'validate_captcha'})
                  .then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Autosubmit when what happens? When the page loads? When something is clicked that is not directly associated with the form? On what basis do you wish to autosubmit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You can't just tell us what code you want and get it handed to you on a silver platter; you need to make an effort and we'll help you where you get stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autosubmit a form in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430590/how-to-autosubmit-a-form-in-javascript)

Comment: Iam tired and did my best but didnt work

Comment: only the time which worked submited without the inputs values

Comment: I want it submit the inputs values too

Comment: @JosephSible Iam starter and I see JS hard so I late it

Comment: @MosiaThabo believe me I tried it and didnt work

Comment: post what you actually tried, and describe the issue. your form only has a *recaptcha* response, auto submitting it does not make much sense

Comment: On what basis do you wish to submit the form? i.e. on page load, on mouse over, or key int or on what?

Comment: Iam didnt speak English well

Comment: and my subject will get bind because grammar

Comment: @MosiaThabo once the page load

Comment: I make this page to filter bots only

Comment: See the answer below for submitting that form on load.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, with this little trick you can achieve your goals:

using Plain Javascript - this is how you can submit a form:

```
  document.getElementById("YourFormIdHere").submit();
```

If you wish to submit that form only when the captcha is provided then you must run if statements.

First Stop the form from submitting, so that you can evaluate the Captcha before it's submitted.

```
document.getElementById("FormIdHere").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

from Here, you want to check if the captcha value was submitted. First try to get the value of the Captcha

```
var Captcha = document.GetElementById("capture ID here").value;

//check if captcha has value
if(Captcha){
    //then submit your form here
    document.getElementById("YourFormIdHere").submit();
}
```

If Captcha value was empty, the form won't submit, thus forcing the user to create the captcha.

Comment: worked but the captcha response = null 
didnt get the value 

check here 
https://serving.photos.photobox.com/707474000e91f1676c4b5552a5bd009c6f4fee681ab1c944ba77423b9b43b84d6e0e1dda.jpg

Comment: this is my problem

Comment: Well, if it's empty then no value was received. It means your captcha didn't have any value. But the question has been answered because the form is submitting on page load. Please mark as answered. If no value is showing then no value was submitted and it is no longer within the context of the question. Somehow that captcha is not submitting the results on page load. Remember you said you're checking the bots?

Comment: when I click submit manually work with value
notice 
I use this before the scirpt

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo $captcha_site_key ?>"></script>
</head>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo $captcha_site_key ?>', {action:'validate_captcha'})
                  .then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: Because these are event driven actions, it doesn't not worry where you put your code... either before or after. But I understand.

Comment: Ahh I see now, well... The right thing todo is to ensure that document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response') has value, before you submit the form. But if it's empty, you shouldn't submit the form.

Comment: Good idean I tried to do it but failed can you give me the code ?

Comment: not work I want to give you notice Google Recaptcha didnt add value = "token"
it is make by js too

Comment: Nice, So does that work the way you want it? I see the form will only submit if there is value.

Comment: google captcha v3 didnt put the value on the source code never

Comment: I sent you on gmail hangouts

Comment: you should get the value from "grecaptcha"

Comment: `grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo $captcha_site_key ?>', {action:'validate_captcha'})
                  .then(function(token) {
            document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
        });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Mosia Thabo for helping me

The JS code is

explain :- first `setAttribute('value', 'token');`

then wait 1 second then submit `myform`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response')..setAttribute("value", token);‏

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){ 
    window.setTimeout(document.myform.submit.bind(document.myform), 100);
};
 </script>
```