# How to autosubmit data html form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have this simple form:

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="story.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Show files">
<input type="hidden" name="emailp" id="emailp" value="">
</form>
```

I fill the "value" with a querystring parameter by external iframe and javascript.
Ok. Now I need to send this data to a php file.
My idea was go for autosubmit.
Now I can do that with a button like "show files", but I dont need a button but something that send the value automatically.
Is it possible do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript autosubmit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102889/javascript-autosubmit-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call a this JS code that submits the form after you set the value of the input.

```
document.getElementById("storyForm").submit();
```

HTML:

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="story.php" method="POST" id="storyForm">
<input type="submit" value="Show files">
<input type="hidden" name="emailp" id="emailp" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add an ID to that form you could do it like this .

`$('#FORM_ID').submit();` with jQuery

```
form = document.getElementById('FORM_ID');
   form.submit();
```

or with JavaScript