# Missing HTTP Referrer info on IE/FF (works well on Chrome/Safari)

Tags: php, http, firefox, redirect, http-headers

I have `page1.php` with this code:

```
<form action="/redirect.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="destination" type="hidden" value="a"/>
<input type="submit" value="Click here"></form>
```

and this is `redirect.php`:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.default.com"; 

if(isset($_POST['destination'])){

    switch ($_POST['destination']) {

    case "a":
        $url = "http://www.domain1.com";
        break;

    case "b":
        $url = "http://www.domain2.com";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://www.default.com";
    }
}

header( "refresh:1;url=$url" );

?>  
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>Redirecting, Please wait</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created the redirect page this way because it's important for me that it would load and display certain content, rather than redirect straight away (and thus, it yields out a 200 code, rather than a 302 code).

However, only on Chrome and Safari, the Headers of the redirect contain information about the referring url, which is `redirect.php`, and thus, for example, the owner of `domain1.com` will know that the visitor came from `mydomain.com/redirect.php`.

But on IE and FF, the referrer in the headers is null. What is causing this different behavior and how can I fix it to have them carry the same referrer info as well?

Comment: In this case, I think that [autosubmitted forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397566/how-to-autosubmit-data-html-form) would be your best shot. I haven't tested it, but I don't a reason why the browser would not send the referer.

Comment: @machineaddict where do you suggest to put an autosubmit form? on `redirect.php` or `page1.php`? I didn't really understood how this could solve the issue... and I don't want to have the URL address appear in the body of any of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
header("Location: ".$url."");
```

Comment: using `location` would turn the page into a 302 redirect, and thus would prevent loading its content, which is vital for me.

Comment: maybe here you can find some useful thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660818/how-to-redirect-preserving-original-referrer-field

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: @gfcodix I don't own the domain into which the visitors are being redirected, so only the "cheating" option in that post might be relevant, however I didn't really understood that answer, for example, it doesn't say what does `detect_referal.php` should contain. also that question is about a 302 redirect (using `Location`), while mine is a refresh with 200 code, so not sure it would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Working example (tried on FF 27.0.1):

File `page1.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Starting page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="redirect.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="destination" value="a">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

File `redirect.php`:

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.default.com"; 

if(isset($_POST['destination'])){

    switch ($_POST['destination']) {

    case "a":
        $url = "http://www.domain.com";
        break;

    case "b":
        $url = "http://www.examples.com";
        break;

    default:
        $url = "http://www.example.com";
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Landing page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Redirecting, Please wait</div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = '<?php echo $url;?>';
    }, 4000);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**How it's working:** After clicking the button `Click here` on `page1.php`, the post data is sent and the domain `http://www.domain.com` is chosen. With javascript, after 4 seconds after window onload, the browser will redirect the user to `http://www.domain.com`. I have watched the referer headers in `Firebug` and they were sent.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mention it in the original question, but I prefer a way in which the destination URL would only appear in the HTTP request (like it happens now, with the meta refresh) and not in the document body (such as in the case of using a javascript redirect)

Comment: If what you like doesn't work, you do it the other way around. Many things in life don't work the way you like, but you still have to do ;)

Answer (score -1):

Confused. Redirect and page refresh is not equally. And more - not all browsers support refresh header.

Comment: your response should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: this redirect not works with ALL browser. Popular, not popular.. It important?

Comment: @gfcodix why my response is not answer?

Comment: @deep because the question is about how to make FF/IE send the same referrer information. it is not about whether this redirection method is the best practice or not.

Comment: @deep because it is more like a comment. Do you think an answer like this will be selected as the right answer ever? By the way I make this explanation so that you don't harm your stackoverflow profile, you are welcome.

Comment: @rockyraw i'm always think for best practice. Show rigth way for you? You must send Location header (if need same origin window/tab) or open new tab for redirection page, and this page must be contain meta refresh tag.

Comment: @gfcodix i think correct is hint and not a complete response.