# Is there a way to make an automated POST request?

Tags: php, http, post, http-headers, http-post

I have a `page.php` that dynamically generates a URL address `$url`, to which I would like to redirect the visitor.

I don't want to redirect him right away from that same page, [because of the problem I encountered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138689/missing-http-referrer-info-on-ie-ff-works-well-on-chrome-safari).

**Therefore, is it possible for `page.php` to automatically generate a POST request with the value of `$url` (1 second after the page opens, without interaction from the visitor)**, into `page2.php` (that would process the request and make a 302 redirect to `$url`)?

*I am interested in this method because I want `$url` to be sent in the **HTTP header/content**, and not in the URL itself, nor in the body of any page (and I know that this is what the POST method does, though it usually requires action from the visitor).

Comment: Posts can be done without user consent, like ajax, html meta, php header, autosubmitted forms. What do you want to achieve? It seems that you are getting complicated over a simple problem.

Comment: @machineaddict I want to achieve a redirect method, in which the URL is read only from the HTTP header/content, that allows me to first include content in the body of the redirect, [as elaborated here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138689/missing-http-referrer-info-on-ie-ff-works-well-on-chrome-safari). But doing so causes FF/IE to drop the referer information. Therefore I want the redirect to transfer the above info (`$url`), into another 302 redirect, that wouldn't drop the referer information, and would continue the redirect process without user intraction.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that User goes to a page automatically and quiclky come back to the page wich he comes from?

**page.php**

```
<script language=javascript>

function submeter(){
        document.page2.submit();
}

function start_sending(){
       var seconds = 1000;
window.setInterval(function(){submeter()},seconds);  
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="start_sending();">
<form action="page2.php" method="post" name="page2">
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
header("Location:page.php");
?>
```

Comment: No, The user shouldn't come back. he should be transfered into a new URL - `$url`, [you can see sample code for how it is generated, here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138689/missing-http-referrer-info-on-ie-ff-works-well-on-chrome-safari)

Comment: @rockyraw: so, what is stopping you from doing that? Flavio only showed you a way of doing it.

Comment: I give it a +1 since it is useful, though I think what I'm looking for simply can't be done - I thought there might be away for the URL that was carried in the HTTP body of `page.php` to be "forwarded" to the HTTP body of `page2.php`